# Scope of variables declared inside `if constexpr` blocks

Tags: c++, scope, c++17, constexpr

Is that ill-formed or is just the compiler (g++-7 in my case) is just still buggy? because it says that `n` is not defined.

```
template<class T>
auto tup(T const& t)
{
    if constexpr(hana::length(t)() % 2)
        auto n = hana::append(t, nullptr);
    else
        auto const& n = t;

    return n;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << hana::length(tup(std::tuple(3, "h", 'c'))) << '\n';
}
```

`n` will be always defined, no matter for which branch will the compiler go.

Comment: This error would make sense if the scoping rules for `if constexpr` matched the standard scoping rules for `if` statements, since the variable declaration would be only scoped to the body of the `if` or `else`. But I don't know how `if constexpr` is supposed to work and therefore have no idea if that's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: It's ill-formed. I'd be surprised if those `auto` declarations even compiled, unless there were surrounding `{...}` blocks, but in any case the variables disappear with their scopes, which terminate at the `else` and the `;` before the `return` statement respectively,

Comment: @EJP I thought that after compilation the resulting code was the equivalent of "copy-pasting" the selected parts.

Comment: Note you can just use two `return` statements. A discarded `return` statement does not affect deduction of a placeholder return type.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Certainly not. I don't know where you got that idea. It's a compiled language, not a clipboard.

Comment: It would be nice, if `if constexpr()` would enable the use of alternative declarations of a local variable in a templated method or function, depending on the incoming types. As in: `if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,short>) typedef int intermediate; else typedef long long intermediate;` So if T is int, intermediate will be long long, but if T is short, intermediate will be int. Of course, that can be easily achieved with a helper template struct, but it would be nice, if those structs could be avoided.

Comment: @KaiPetzke The helper struct is even already written for you: it's `std::conditional`.

Comment: both n are scoped within if and else respectively, hence it will be gone when PC reaches at return statement. Don't you get undefined var n error when you compile this?

Comment: @VishalSahu "because it says that n is not defined" from the first sentence of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed because each `n` is restricted to the scope of the single statement declaring it.

C++17 draft N4659 [stmt.select]/1 says:

> The substatement in a *selection-statement* (each substatement, in the `else` form of the `if` statement) implicitly defines a block scope ([basic.scope]). If the substatement in a selection-statement is a single statement and not a *compound-statement*, it is as if it was rewritten to be a compound statement containing the original substatement. [ *Example:*

```
if (x)
  int i;
```

> can be equivalently rewritten as

```
if (x) {
  int i;
}
```

> Thus after the `if` statement, `i` is no longer in scope. - *end example* ]

This rule applies to all `for`, `while`, `switch`, and `if` statements - whether or not the `constexpr` keyword is used with `if`.

Comment: Really bad to see the C++ standard committee don't see why the scoping rules for the `constexpr` statement must be different to runtime scoping rules. So, another keyword for those rules, eh?

Comment: @Andry You're saying you want things to be less consistent? And what should happen when a name declared in only one `if constexpr` branch is used after the `if` statement?

Comment: I want just say the compile-time `if` expression has being developed to replace the `#if-#else-#endif` in the first place, to move from preprocessor programming into the `constexpr` procedural programming, but instead of that they added more ambiguity into this and didn't resolve that in easy way. Why we need another level of complication here, isn't the new C++ already overloaded of syntax sugar masses which in a closer look just a pile of overengineered constructions?

Answer (score 2):

`constexpr` change nothing in this case.

It's exactly like in this example

```
int foo (int a)
 {
   if ( a == 0 )
    {
      int r = 0;
    }
   else
    {
      int r = 0;
    }

   return r;
 }
```

`r` is defined in both cases. And with the same value.

But the scope of `r` is limited to the `if` and don't reach the `return`.

If you can solve the problem returning immediatly; I mean

```
template<class T>
auto tup(T const& t)
{
    if constexpr(hana::length(t)() % 2)
        return hana::append(t, nullptr);
    else
        return t;
}
```